# if else statement both execute one after another in page scroll event

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have the following code which should do something once the scrollbar gets passed the y coordinate of an element.

However once I scroll bellow that element which gives me a negative y value it starts behaving weird altering between if and else on any subsequent down scroll. If I get above the element things get back to normal.

```
let timeout = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    if (element.getBoundingClientRect().y <= 0) {
      element.style.position = 'fixed';
    } else {
      element.style.position = 'relative';
    }
  }, 50)
});
```

Does anyone have a clue to what's going on here? The timeout here is just to reduce the execution.

Comment: What is the `.y` value when you set it to `fixed`? If it is greater than 0 it will set it to `relative` on the next scroll, which will in turn trigger `fixed` again etc.

Comment: oh... you just gave me the answer it changes the position ...

Comment: Glad it helped!